# Triple monitors on Debian wheezy

Tags: xorg

I have nVidia GTS 450 on Asus Z97 motherboard. Today I bought a new screen, so in total I have three now - two 27" are connected to the GTS 450 card and one 20" is connected to the motherboard output. The big screens are both working, but I can't figure out how to make the small screen - attached to the motherboard - work.

I'm running gdm3 and couldn't find anything in the gui config apps. Would a reinstall of proprietary graphic drivers come in handy?

**Update**
My xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 340.65  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-11)  Tue Dec  2 09:59:38 PST 2014


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And that's pretty much it

Comment: I assume this is configured in `xorg.conf`. Can you paste your `xorg.conf`?

Comment: @FaheemMitha updated my post

Comment: I don't see any mention of the motherboard graphics in the xorg.conf. Google xinerama, you will find a ton of sites that will help you configure it.

Comment: A little googling seems to be in order. For example "configuring nvidia xorg three monitors" turns up some hits. And you can try variations on that. E.g. leaving otu the "three monitors" or the "xorg" or both. As @Ariel points out, there is no mention of the motherboard card in your `xorg.conf`. Write about your motherboard and the (I assume onboard) video card in your question.